# "CA key usage check failed: keyCertSign bit is not set" when chain validation on PDF signature

Tags: java, validation, pdf, digital-signature, x509certificate

i am having trouble validating the trust chain of a fairly simple signed pdf document.

i can verify the document signature ok. but validating the cert chain seems to blow up. 
i am assumming the anchor cert is the issue.is that correct?

the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: CA key usage check failed: keyCertSign bit is not set
```

this is what i did

1. the signed PDF document is this [sample signed pdf from adobe](http://blogs.adobe.com/security/SampleSignedPDFDocument.pdf).
2. the trust anchor i used was [the adobe CA cert](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/GeoTrust_CA_for_Adobe.pem)
3. the code to validate the chain.

   ```
   X509CertSelector targetConstraints = new X509CertSelector();
   KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
   keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\src\\xxxxxxx\\testanchorcerts"), "password".toCharArray());
   PKIXBuilderParameters validateParams = new PKIXBuilderParameters(keystore, targetConstraints); 
   CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
   CertPath certPathToValidate = factory.generateCertPath(certificatesToValidate);
   CertPathValidator certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");
   PKIXCertPathValidatorResult result = (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult)  certPathValidator.validate(certPathToValidate, validateParams);
   System.out.println("VALIDATION START====================");
   System.out.println(result);
   System.out.println("VALIDATION END====================");
   ```

The certs in the actual signed document are below

```
===Show All Certificates==========
Principal:CN=Adobe Root CA, OU=Adobe Trust Services, O=Adobe Systems Incorporated, C=US
Issuer:CN=Adobe Root CA, OU=Adobe Trust Services, O=Adobe Systems Incorporated, C=US
Serial Number:1042070824
Subject Key ID:#041482b7384a93aa9b10ef80bbd954e2f10ffb809cde
Issuer Key ID:#3016801482b7384a93aa9b10ef80bbd954e2f10ffb809cde
============
Principal:CN=GeoTrust CA for Adobe, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
Issuer:CN=Adobe Root CA, OU=Adobe Trust Services, O=Adobe Systems Incorporated, C=US
Serial Number:1042070965
Subject Key ID:#0414ab8059c365836d1d7d13bd19c3ec1a8f0d476aa3
Issuer Key ID:#3016801482b7384a93aa9b10ef80bbd954e2f10ffb809cde
============
Principal:EMAILADDRESS=jbharris@adobe.com, CN=John B Harris, O=Adobe Systems Incorporated, L=San Jose, ST=CA, C=US
Issuer:CN=GeoTrust CA for Adobe, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
Serial Number:514
Subject Key ID:
Issuer Key ID:#30168014ab8059c365836d1d7d13bd19c3ec1a8f0d476aa3
```

any help or ideas are most appreciated.

-lp

Comment: As a first observation, the Root and the CA certificates both have the *keyCertSign bit* set. Thus, are you sure you have the correct inputs in your code?

Comment: @mkl how did u observe that the Root/CA have keyCertSign bit set? the root and CA and the signer cert were all part of the pkcs7 signature. Since i am extracting the certs from the pkcs7 structure i *may* have corrupted them. so is the issue with the trust anchor or the cert chain?

Comment: I merely opened the PDF in Adobe reader, inspected the certificate chain in the signature properties, exported the certificates, and opened them using the tools available in Windows.